# Filling the blank using first. in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a simple data which looks like this

```
+----------+------+--------+
| cis_code | yymm | sector |
+----------+------+--------+
| CTAGBTH  | 1707 | BANK   |
| CTAGBTH  | 1706 |        |
| CTAGBTH  | 1705 |        |
| CTAGBTH  | 1703 |        |
| CTAGBTH  | 1702 | RETAIL |
| CTAGBTH  | 1701 |        |
| CTAGBTH  | 1612 |        |
| CTAGBTG  | 1703 |        |
| CTAGBTG  | 1702 | AGRI   |
| CTAGBTG  | 1701 |        |
| CTAGBTG  | 1612 | RETAIL |
| CTAGBET  | 1705 |        |
| CTAGBET  | 1510 | FSI    |
| CTAGBET  | 1504 |        |
+----------+------+--------+
```

in this problem I want to create a new variable sector_summary where the blanks should be replaced by the sector with the change in cid_code. I have tried using both first.yymm and first.sector but unfortunately nothing is working. I have also tried some if statements but not sure if the if statements would work with all the conditions. The data should look like this

```
+-----------+-------+---------+---------------+
| cis_code  | yymm  |  sector |  Sector_Group |
+-----------+-------+---------+---------------+
| CTAGBET   |  1705 |         |               |
| CTAGBET   |  1510 |  FSI    |  FSI          |
| CTAGBET   | 1504  |         |  FSI          |
| CTAGBTG   |  1703 |         |               |
| CTAGBTG   | 1702  | AGRI    |  AGRI         |
| CTAGBTG   |  1701 |         |  AGRI         |
| CTAGBTG   | 1612  | RETAIL  | RETAIL        |
| CTAGBTH   | 1707  | BANK    |  BANK         |
| CTAGBTH   |  1706 |         |  BANK         |
| CTAGBTH   | 1705  |  BANK   |               |
| CTAGBTH   | 1703  |  BANK   |               |
| CTAGBTH   | 1702  | RETAIL  | RETAIL        |
| CTAGBTH   |  1701 |         |  RETAIL       |
| CTAGBTH   |  1612 |         |  RETAIL       |
+-----------+-------+---------+---------------+
```

So basically if there is a blank sector for the a given yymm the sector group would also be blank for the consequent months until and unless there is another sector which gets replaced and that will further be there for the next months.
Please let me know how to go about it

Answer (score 2):

You just need to retain the values.  It also looks like you will need to sort the data (or use `NOTSORTED` option on the `BY` statement).

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by cis_code descending yymm ;
  if first.cis_code or not missing(sector) then sector_group=sector;
  retain sector_group;
run;
```